# Managing node.js async in a for loop

Tags: node.js, mongodb, asynchronous

All,

The problem definition: I have several inputs that I need to coordinate. The thought was to loop through the main file and utilize async.waterfall to process the remaining files. the problem I am running into is the following:

1)  The loop works perfectly, I see all the correct records process
2)  the async does not process until the loop has completed, and process the last record over and over.

the console looks like the following:

-- from loop -- record 1
-- from loop -- record 2
-- from loop -- record 3
-- from loop -- record 4
-- from loop -- record 5
-- from loop -- record 6
..............
-- from loop -- record 329

-- from async -- record 329
-- from async -- record 329
-- from async -- record 329
-- from async -- record 329
-- from async -- record 329
..............
-- from async -- record 329

the code looks like the following:

```
MongoClient.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/preInc", function(err, db) {
if(err) { return console.dir(err); }
var collection = db.collection('resource_Tbl');
collection.find().toArray(function(err, items)
    {
        if(err) {
            return console.dir(err); }
        else {
            test = items;
        }
        for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++)
        {
            var temp = items[i]._id.toHexString();
            var name = items[i].name;
            console.dir(temp + "-|-" + name);
            Async.waterfall([
                    function getGeoAddress(callback)
                    {
                        console.dir(temp + "   " + name);
                        callback(null, 'unknown');
                    },
                ],
                function (err, results)
                {
                    if (err)
                    {
                        console.log(err);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                    }
                });
        }
        res.render('heatmap', { data: test, headerX:'preInc.org' });
    });
});
```

});

I am continuing to work through this but...

Thank you in advance,

roger...

Answer (score 0):

`async` module doesn't actually *block* the flow. All async processes are put into the event-loop, which only gets picked up with the main thread completes your particular operation. So in your case you should be doing something like `async.each` or `async.eachSeries`.

You problem is analogous to the following:

```
for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    console.log(i);
  }, 1000);
}
```

This would output 10 times "9", since it gets executed only at the next iteration, which, at that point, `i = 9`.

I'm not 100% sure what you mean with the following statement:

> The thought was to loop through the main file and utilize async.waterfall to process the remaining files.

But there are really two solutions:

If you need the results from processing *each* of the files, then use async.each, like previously mentioned. For example:

```
async.each(items, function(item, next) {}, function() {
 // Here all the files has been processed, can return to the requester via res.send() or res.render();
   res.render();
});
```

If you *don't* need to use the results, and the operation can be processed at a later time. Then in this case, you can use an immediate function as follows:

```
for(var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
  // create and call an immediate function
  (function(i) {
    // now i would be 0..items.length-1 correctly. 
    async.waterfall([], function() {});
  } (i);
}
```

This would create events that gets put into the event loop, scheduled to be called at a later time, but with the correct scope.

Comment: ahhh, I am beginning to see the light, on the async.each (this gets me past my first problem), can you stack the functions in a similar manner as the waterfall? function1{}, function2{} res.render()?

Thank you for your response, I will try the async.each tonight.

Comment: @AEgirSystems not quite. `async.each` is essentially just a for loop. But doesn't really replace what async.waterfall/series does. Depends really what you want to accomplish. Give me a little bit more details, and I can provide perhaps with a gist of the example you want to give.

Comment: apologies for the delay, this is an attempt to create a programmatic join. 

I will pull the main document, say customer. then start and work through another collection that has all the contacts (a contact can be associated with other customers). this is basically three collections with a one to many relationship.

Comment: @AEgirSystems Then this definitely sounds like the first option: using `async.each`. Let me know if you need any sample, and I can update my answer with some sort of github gist.